# Redux React-Native (What's the diffrence using useSelector in react-redux than use connect?)

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I think they were same because they extract the content of the store. How could it makes it diffrent

Comment: `useSelector` is a hook that you can use inside functional component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking about the different use case for Hooks vs Redux.

Rule of thumb to use Hooks over Redux:

1. For a single view app that doesn’t load or save state
2. Has no
   asynchronous I/O or not using the network
3. Does not share state with non-child components.
4. Does need some ephemeral state (UI state or local state)